# How do I search by last name in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, search

I'm trying to create a method to search for a surname in an array of full names, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here:

```
        public int searchRegisterByFamilyName(String familyName) {
            
             int searchByFamilyName(Name [] list,  String fullname) {
                 for (int i= 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            
            String[] splitted = fullname.split(" ");

            String firstName;
            String surName;  
            firstName = splitted[0];
            surName = splitted[1];
            
            String[] splittedd = familyName.split(" ");

            String FirstName;
            String lastName;     
            FirstName = splittedd[0];
            lastName = splittedd[1];
                              
                              if (list[i].surName.equals(lastName)) 
                                  return i;
                              }
                          }
                          return -1;
        }
```

The names in the array are full names so I have to split it to search for just the last name.

Ideally, I want it to accept a String argument and it returns true or false depending on whether a name exists with the respective last name.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, can you provide a code that is compiling?

Comment: There are many issues in the code, but lemme ask you a few questions... What's familyName and what's fullname? Why do you have a method inside another method?

Comment: It is not possible to know how your names are constructed.  And you would be better off returning a Name class that contains name information (e.g first, last, mi).  Then instead of returning an index you can return a Name object or even a list of Name objects which have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The `Stream` way:

```
Set<Name> matchedNames = names
.stream()
.filter(n -> n.getFamilyName().equals(requestedFamilyName))
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This will give all (if any) matched names